# How to install python cntk in CentOS linux without anaconda

Tags: python, centos, cntk

I have a CentOS 7.4 GPU machine.

I tried to install cntk in the machine. I cannot use the pip files as they are for ubuntu (I tried to install with them and get seg fault when I import cntk).

I compiled the cloned cntk successfully. However I when I try to get the python version, I run into troubles. I did

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

in $cntk_root/bindings/python

and get

> building '_cntk_py' extension
>
> swigging cntk/cntk_py.i to cntk/cntk_py_wrap.cpp
>
> swig -python -c++ -D_MSC_VER -I../../Source/CNTKv2LibraryDll/API -I../../bindings/common -Werror -threads -o cntk/cntk_py_wrap.cpp cntk/cntk_py.i
>
> cntk/cntk_py.i:92: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
>
> error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1

It must be simpler than this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with your above problem but if you relax the constrain of not using Conda and follow these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-cntk-on-linux) I can say that it will work since I did it a few weeks ago on RHEL 7 using the cntk release 2.2.

Note, release 2.2 assumes that /var/lock is writable which is not true for me. If you follow the instructions above you need to open CrossProcessMutex.h and replace /var/lock/ by a writable directory.